# Бот на Python 3.8 для VK просто так пишет сообщения

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот, обработка-ошибок

Я написал бота для вк, но почему то, он пишет всем подряд, хотя ему ничего не писали

код:

```
import random
import time
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

#ВХОД ОТ  ИМЕНИ ГРУППЫ
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="f61acc2a7b90f3772f9606a83e7b2ea1fbec2d3dgg6786fdbabe5ce70656c626f200f70147a494d9902b9")

#КОМАНДЫ
commands_list = ['тз']
#ПРИВЕТСТВИЯ
greetings = ['привет', 'здравствуй','ку','хелло','прив', 'начать', 'меню', 'доброе утро', 'добрый день', 'добрый вечер', 'здравствуйте', 'салют','здорово', 'приветствую']
#Список цветов для ТЗ
colors_list = ['Чёрный', 'Серый', 'Белый', 'Лиловый', 'Бирюзовый', 'Сиреневый', 'Пурпурный', 'Фиолетовый', 'Мятный', 'Голубой', 'Синий', 'Фисташковый', 'Салатовый', 'Травяной', 'Зелёный',
'Золотой', 'Янтарный', 'Жёлтый', 'Хаки', 'Какао', 'Бежевый', 'Персиковый', 'Коралловый', 'Оранжевый', 'Коричневый', 'Розовый', 'Фуксия', 'Вишневый', 'Красный', 'Бордовый',
'Изумрудный', 'Кремовый']
#Список тем для ТЗ
Order_list = ['Обложка', 'Рекламный креатив', 'Баннер', 'Превью', 'Визитка', 'Флаер', 'Афиша']
#Тематика ТЗ
Thematics = ['Цветочный магазин', 'Такси', 'Телефоны и Ноутбуки', 'Веганская еда', 'Спортивный магазин', 'Детские игрушки', 'Рок-концерт', 'Косметология', 'Медицина',
'Планетарий', 'Аквапарк', 'Хлебопекарня', 'Выпечка тортов', 'Тур-агенство (курорты)', 'Авиалинии', 'Аниме-фестиваль', 'Выставка', 'супрематизма', 'Паракмахерская', 'Магазин мёда',
'Лего', 'Мясной рынок', 'Пиццерия', 'Сантехника', 'Зоомагазин', 'Скейтпарк', 'Ремонт космических кораблей', 'музей космонавтики', 'Филармония', 'Выставка ретро автомобилей', 'Пошив одежды',
'Архитектурное бюро', 'Тату Мастер', 'Учителя защиты от тёмных искусств', 'Художник', 'Ювелирная мастерская', 'Корма для животных']

#######################################################################################################################

print('Бот запущен!')

#Прослушивание
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
vk = vk_session.get_api()



for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:

        #Приветствие
        if event.text.lower() in greetings:
            vk.messages.send(
                user_id=event.user_id,
                random_id=event.random_id,
                message='Привет, я Креативный Дизайнер!\n\nЯ сгенерирую для тебя рандомное техническое задание.' + \
                            ' С моей помощью ты сможешь набраться опыта, пополнить своё портфолио новыми работами и развить креативность. ' + \
                            'Готов начать?\n\nНапиши мне команду «ТЗ»'
            )

        #Техническое задание
        elif event.text.lower() in commands_list[0]:
                #Сообщение
                colors_list_1 = random.randint(0, len(colors_list) - 1)
                colors_list_2 = random.randint(0, len(colors_list) - 1)
                # чтобы цвета не дублировались
                while colors_list_1 == colors_list_2:
                    colors_list_2 = random.randint(0, len(colors_list) - 1)
                #Отправка сообщения
                vk.messages.send(
                        user_id=event.user_id,
                        random_id=event.random_id,
                        message= 'Техническое задание:\n\nНужно сделать:\n– '+ Order_list [ random.randint(0, len(Order_list) - 1) ] + \
                            '\n\nТематика:\n– '+ Thematics [ random.randint(0, len(Thematics) - 1) ]+'\n\nОсновные цвета:\n– '+ \
                            colors_list [colors_list_1] + ', ' + colors_list [(colors_list_2) ]
                )
        #Неправильная команда
        else:
            vk.messages.send(
                user_id=event.user_id,
                random_id=event.random_id,
                message='Я вас не понимаю.\nНапишите «ТЗ»'
                )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это означает что при выполнении запроса возникает какая-то ошибка, и VK API повторяет запросы снова и снова, ожидая ответы от сервера. Проверьте свой код на наличие ошибок.

Comment: @Максим там нету ошибок, разве не так? Я ведь скинул код

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте написать так:

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

    if event.to_me:

        #Приветствие
        if event.text.lower() in greetings:
            vk.messages.send(
                user_id=event.user_id,
                random_id=event.random_id,
                message='Привет, я Креативный Дизайнер!\n\nЯ сгенерирую для тебя рандомное техническое задание.' + \
                            ' С моей помощью ты сможешь набраться опыта, пополнить своё портфолио новыми работами и развить креативность. ' + \
                            'Готов начать?\n\nНапиши мне команду «ТЗ»'
            )

        #Техническое задание
        elif event.text.lower() in commands_list[0]:
                #Сообщение
                colors_list_1 = random.randint(0, len(colors_list) - 1)
                colors_list_2 = random.randint(0, len(colors_list) - 1)
                # чтобы цвета не дублировались
                while colors_list_1 == colors_list_2:
                    colors_list_2 = random.randint(0, len(colors_list) - 1)
                #Отправка сообщения
                vk.messages.send(
                        user_id=event.user_id,
                        random_id=event.random_id,
                        message= 'Техническое задание:\n\nНужно сделать:\n– '+ Order_list [ random.randint(0, len(Order_list) - 1) ] + \
                            '\n\nТематика:\n– '+ Thematics [ random.randint(0, len(Thematics) - 1) ]+'\n\nОсновные цвета:\n– '+ \
                            colors_list [colors_list_1] + ', ' + colors_list [(colors_list_2) ]
                )
        #Неправильная команда
        else:
            vk.messages.send(
                user_id=event.user_id,
                random_id=event.random_id,
                message='Я вас не понимаю.\nНапишите «ТЗ»'
                )
```